# Generating random integer in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I need to generate a random integer between 0 - 1023 in vhdl however I couldn't find a good resource for this on the internet. Is there anyone help me please ?

Comment: [Generating random numbers in a VHDL testbench](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2013/08/generating-random-numbers-in-vhdl.html).  I found it by plugging the title of your question into Google.  There are some additional links at the top of that post that go into greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example for generation of integers in range [0 : 1023] with uniform (even) distribution.

Note that the `floor` operation must be used after multiplication with the max value + 1, in this case 1023 + 1 = 1024, in order to ensure uniform (even) distribution of all integer values in [0 : 1023], since using integer without floor (thus `integer(x * 1023)`) as in the example "Generating random numbers in a VHDL testbench" from the comment will cause rounding to nearest (and up from half), thus give only half probability for the first and last values (0 and 1023) in the range.

```
entity tb is
end entity;

library ieee;
use ieee.math_real.uniform;
use ieee.math_real.floor;

architecture sim of tb is
begin
  process is
    variable seed1 : positive;
    variable seed2 : positive;
    variable x : real;
    variable y : integer;
  begin
    seed1 := 1;
    seed2 := 1;
    for n in 1 to 10 loop
      uniform(seed1, seed2, x);
      y := integer(floor(x * 1024.0));
      report "Random number in 0 .. 1023: " & integer'image(y);
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, actually I wanna create the random number to use on fpga bord. I wıll create a hot cold game and guess the random number. Can I use thıs code ın vhd fıle or thıs ıs just for test bench ?

Comment: For a more synthesize-able version look for LFSR random number generator..

Comment: This is only for test bench.  As @Oldfart said, look for [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) for a hardware implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment I wrote "look for LFSR random number generator" but there are some pitfalls using those which may not be immediately obvious.

- They can not generate the value zero.
- They can not produce the same number twice.
- Every number appears only once in 2^n cycles.
- The numbers are highly 'related' by a factor two.

I wrote and tested a 16-bit generator trying to work around some of the problems above. But please realize that the result will always be a ***pseudo*** random number so do not expect true randomness.

I used Verilog because I write that about five times faster then VHDL but translation should be trivial for a VHDL programmer.

```
//
// 16-bit Pseudo random number generator
// Using Linear Feedback Shift Register
//
// No copyright : Freeware, 18 Nov. 2018 
//
//

// The LFSR polynomial is taken from a (by now almost famous)
// application note from Xilinx.
// Those polynomials are selected for using minimal logic
// not for getting good 'randomness'.
// Using an LFSR alone is not good:
// - They can not generate the value zero.
// - They can not produce the same number twice.
// - Every number appears only once in 2^n cycles.
// - The numbers are highly 'related' by a factor two.
//  e.g. an 8-bit LFSR would take steps:
//  1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 33, 66, 132, 41, 82 
//  
//  Therefore I use only 16 of 32 bits and re-order
//  the selected bits. Even then it may take a while before,
//  (what our feelings say!) a more random sequence of number
//  appears. 
//  
// 
// Other LFSRs polynomials (From Xilinx app. note) 
//  32 =  32,31,30,10,0 (used here)
//  40 =  40,21,19,2,0
//  48 =  48,28,27,1,0
//  56 =  56,22,21,1,0
//  64 =  64, 4, 3,1,0
//  72 =  72,53,47,6,0
//  80 =  80,38,35,3,0
//  88 =  88,72,71,1,0
//  96 =  96,49,47,2,0
// 112 = 112,45,43,2,0
// 128 = 128,29,27,2,0
// 
// 
// Know deficiencies:
// -  Using a seed of zero will only produce zeros. 
//    This module does not check that!
// -  Always running. Might add a 'next' number 
//    input for power savings.
// 

module prng16
// Do NOT change these parameters unless you know what you are doing
#(parameter poly    = 32'hC0000400, // max length 32, bit LFSR bits 31,30,10 are set
            degree  = 32
 )
( 
  input   reset_n,
  input   clk,
  input   set,
  input   [degree-1:0] seed,
  output  [15:0] rnd
);

reg [degree-1:0] lfsr,feedback;

   always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
   begin
      if (!reset_n)
         // Futile attempt to start somewhat random.
         // I know: this value is too big for some values of 
         // degree, but better then too small.
         lfsr <= { {(degree/3){3'b101}},2'b10};
      else
         if (set)
            lfsr <= seed;
         else
            lfsr <= feedback;
   end

integer n;

   always @( * )
   begin
      feedback[0]= lfsr[degree-1];
      for (n=1; n<degree; n=n+1)         
        feedback[n] = poly[n]==1'b0 ? lfsr[n-1] : lfsr[n-1]^lfsr[degree-1];
   end

   // Pick 16 bits (indices randomly chosen)
   assign rnd = { lfsr[27], lfsr[16], lfsr[ 6], lfsr[22], 
                  lfsr[20], lfsr[ 0], lfsr[18], lfsr[26],
                  lfsr[10], lfsr[ 9], lfsr[25], lfsr[19], 
                  lfsr[11], lfsr[ 7], lfsr[28], lfsr[ 8]};

endmodule
```